# How to log the counting number?

Tags: javascript, counter

Here is code to count up numbers...
I want a simple thing, But I'm new to JavaScript so I need your help...

I Just need to " console.log("the number that is counting")... " **Using pure JavaScript.** I don't want HTML or CSS, just javascript ...

**Note:** I execute the code using a button in Articulate Storyline... by the way it's not important just tell me how to log the counting number.

I tried my best but I really need your help...

Here is a Guide to use this code :

https://redstapler.co/countup-js-tutorial-counting-animation/

And here is the code :

```
/*

    countUp.js
    by @inorganik

*/

// target = id of html element or var of previously selected html element where counting occurs
// startVal = the value you want to begin at
// endVal = the value you want to arrive at
// decimals = number of decimal places, default 0
// duration = duration of animation in seconds, default 2
// options = optional object of options (see below)

var CountUp = function(target, startVal, endVal, decimals, duration, options) {

    var self = this;
    self.version = function () { return '1.9.3'; };

    // default options
    self.options = {
        useEasing: true, // toggle easing
        useGrouping: true, // 1,000,000 vs 1000000
        separator: ',', // character to use as a separator
        decimal: '.', // character to use as a decimal
        easingFn: easeOutExpo, // optional custom easing function, default is Robert Penner's easeOutExpo
        formattingFn: formatNumber, // optional custom formatting function, default is formatNumber above
        prefix: '', // optional text before the result
        suffix: '', // optional text after the result
        numerals: [] // optionally pass an array of custom numerals for 0-9
    };

    // extend default options with passed options object
    if (options && typeof options === 'object') {
        for (var key in self.options) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(key) && options[key] !== null) {
                self.options[key] = options[key];
            }
        }
    }

    if (self.options.separator === '') {
        self.options.useGrouping = false;
    }
    else {
        // ensure the separator is a string (formatNumber assumes this)
        self.options.separator = '' + self.options.separator;
    }

    // make sure requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame are defined
    // polyfill for browsers without native support
    // by Opera engineer Erik Möller
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz', 'ms', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }
    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };
    }
    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
    }

    function formatNumber(num) {
        var neg = (num < 0),
            x, x1, x2, x3, i, len;
        num = Math.abs(num).toFixed(self.decimals);
        num += '';
        x = num.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? self.options.decimal + x[1] : '';
        if (self.options.useGrouping) {
            x3 = '';
            for (i = 0, len = x1.length; i < len; ++i) {
                if (i !== 0 && ((i % 3) === 0)) {
                    x3 = self.options.separator + x3;
                }
                x3 = x1[len - i - 1] + x3;
            }
            x1 = x3;
        }
        // optional numeral substitution
        if (self.options.numerals.length) {
            x1 = x1.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w) {
                return self.options.numerals[+w];
            })
            x2 = x2.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w) {
                return self.options.numerals[+w];
            })
        }
        return (neg ? '-' : '') + self.options.prefix + x1 + x2 + self.options.suffix;
    }
    // Robert Penner's easeOutExpo
    function easeOutExpo(t, b, c, d) {
        return c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) * 1024 / 1023 + b;
    }
    function ensureNumber(n) {
        return (typeof n === 'number' && !isNaN(n));
    }

    self.initialize = function() { 
        if (self.initialized) return true;

        self.error = '';
        self.d = (typeof target === 'string') ? document.getElementById(target) : target;
        if (!self.d) { 
            self.error = '[CountUp] target is null or undefined'
            return false;
        }
        self.startVal = Number(startVal);
        self.endVal = Number(endVal);
        // error checks
        if (ensureNumber(self.startVal) && ensureNumber(self.endVal)) {
            self.decimals = Math.max(0, decimals || 0);
            self.dec = Math.pow(10, self.decimals);
            self.duration = Number(duration) * 1000 || 2000;
            self.countDown = (self.startVal > self.endVal);
            self.frameVal = self.startVal;
            self.initialized = true;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            self.error = '[CountUp] startVal ('+startVal+') or endVal ('+endVal+') is not a number';
            return false;
        }
    };

    // Print value to target
    self.printValue = function(value) {
        var result = self.options.formattingFn(value);

        if (self.d.tagName === 'INPUT') {
            this.d.value = result;
        }
        else if (self.d.tagName === 'text' || self.d.tagName === 'tspan') {
            this.d.textContent = result;
        }
        else {
            this.d.innerHTML = result;
        }
    };

    self.count = function(timestamp) {

        if (!self.startTime) { self.startTime = timestamp; }

        self.timestamp = timestamp;
        var progress = timestamp - self.startTime;
        self.remaining = self.duration - progress;

        // to ease or not to ease
        if (self.options.useEasing) {
            if (self.countDown) {
                self.frameVal = self.startVal - self.options.easingFn(progress, 0, self.startVal - self.endVal, self.duration);
            } else {
                self.frameVal = self.options.easingFn(progress, self.startVal, self.endVal - self.startVal, self.duration);
            }
        } else {
            if (self.countDown) {
                self.frameVal = self.startVal - ((self.startVal - self.endVal) * (progress / self.duration));
            } else {
                self.frameVal = self.startVal + (self.endVal - self.startVal) * (progress / self.duration);
            }
        }

        // don't go past endVal since progress can exceed duration in the last frame
        if (self.countDown) {
            self.frameVal = (self.frameVal < self.endVal) ? self.endVal : self.frameVal;
        } else {
            self.frameVal = (self.frameVal > self.endVal) ? self.endVal : self.frameVal;
        }

        // decimal
        self.frameVal = Math.round(self.frameVal*self.dec)/self.dec;

        // format and print value
        self.printValue(self.frameVal);

        // whether to continue
        if (progress < self.duration) {
            self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
        } else {
            if (self.callback) self.callback();
        }
    };
    // start your animation
    self.start = function(callback) {
        if (!self.initialize()) return;
        self.callback = callback;
        self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
    };
    // toggles pause/resume animation
    self.pauseResume = function() {
        if (!self.paused) {
            self.paused = true;
            cancelAnimationFrame(self.rAF);
        } else {
            self.paused = false;
            delete self.startTime;
            self.duration = self.remaining;
            self.startVal = self.frameVal;
            requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
        }
    };
    // reset to startVal so animation can be run again
    self.reset = function() {
        self.paused = false;
        delete self.startTime;
        self.initialized = false;
        if (self.initialize()) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(self.rAF);
            self.printValue(self.startVal);
        }
    };
    // pass a new endVal and start animation
    self.update = function (newEndVal) {
        if (!self.initialize()) return;
        newEndVal = Number(newEndVal);
        if (!ensureNumber(newEndVal)) {
            self.error = '[CountUp] update() - new endVal is not a number: '+newEndVal;
            return;
        }
        self.error = '';
        if (newEndVal === self.frameVal) return;
        cancelAnimationFrame(self.rAF);
        self.paused = false;
        delete self.startTime;
        self.startVal = self.frameVal;
        self.endVal = newEndVal;
        self.countDown = (self.startVal > self.endVal);
        self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
    };

    // format startVal on initialization
    if (self.initialize()) self.printValue(self.startVal);
};
```

Comment: There seems to be a whole lot of code here that doesn't really relate at all to the question that you're asking. If you could slim down your example to satisfy the *minimal* portion of [**"minimal, complete, and verifiable example"**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you'd be way more likely to get help.

Comment: You'd want to add a line in the self.count function, where the given code shows self.printValue(self.frameVal), to console.log(self.frameVal). That's the current frame's count value.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with just using `console.log`?  Your question even refers to `console.log` as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the module, he has a `printValue` function. You can log out the number it is printing to the screen. Due to animation and easing, you can see it often prints the same number.

```
 // Print value to target
 self.printValue = function(value) {
     var result = self.options.formattingFn(value);

     console.log(value); // add line to log out 'value'
```

```js
function go() {
  var demo = new CountUp('count', 0, 20);
  if (!demo.error) {  
    demo.start();
  } else {  
    console.error(demo.error);
  }
}

/*

    countUp.js
    by @inorganik

*/

// target = id of html element or var of previously selected html element where counting occurs
// startVal = the value you want to begin at
// endVal = the value you want to arrive at
// decimals = number of decimal places, default 0
// duration = duration of animation in seconds, default 2
// options = optional object of options (see below)

function CountUp(target, startVal, endVal, decimals, duration, options) {

  var self = this;
  self.version = function() {
    return '1.9.3';
  };

  // default options
  self.options = {
    useEasing: true, // toggle easing
    useGrouping: true, // 1,000,000 vs 1000000
    separator: ',', // character to use as a separator
    decimal: '.', // character to use as a decimal
    easingFn: easeOutExpo, // optional custom easing function, default is Robert Penner's easeOutExpo
    formattingFn: formatNumber, // optional custom formatting function, default is formatNumber above
    prefix: '', // optional text before the result
    suffix: '', // optional text after the result
    numerals: [] // optionally pass an array of custom numerals for 0-9
  };

  // extend default options with passed options object
  if (options && typeof options === 'object') {
    for (var key in self.options) {
      if (options.hasOwnProperty(key) && options[key] !== null) {
        self.options[key] = options[key];
      }
    }
  }

  if (self.options.separator === '') {
    self.options.useGrouping = false;
  } else {
    // ensure the separator is a string (formatNumber assumes this)
    self.options.separator = '' + self.options.separator;
  }

  // make sure requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame are defined
  // polyfill for browsers without native support
  // by Opera engineer Erik Möller
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz', 'ms', 'o'];
  for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }
  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
        callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      }, timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };
  }
  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }

  function formatNumber(num) {
    var neg = (num < 0),
      x, x1, x2, x3, i, len;
    num = Math.abs(num).toFixed(self.decimals);
    num += '';
    x = num.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? self.options.decimal + x[1] : '';
    if (self.options.useGrouping) {
      x3 = '';
      for (i = 0, len = x1.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i !== 0 && ((i % 3) === 0)) {
          x3 = self.options.separator + x3;
        }
        x3 = x1[len - i - 1] + x3;
      }
      x1 = x3;
    }
    // optional numeral substitution
    if (self.options.numerals.length) {
      x1 = x1.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w) {
        return self.options.numerals[+w];
      })
      x2 = x2.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w) {
        return self.options.numerals[+w];
      })
    }
    return (neg ? '-' : '') + self.options.prefix + x1 + x2 + self.options.suffix;
  }
  // Robert Penner's easeOutExpo
  function easeOutExpo(t, b, c, d) {
    return c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) * 1024 / 1023 + b;
  }

  function ensureNumber(n) {
    return (typeof n === 'number' && !isNaN(n));
  }

  self.initialize = function() {
    if (self.initialized) return true;

    self.error = '';
    self.d = (typeof target === 'string') ? document.getElementById(target) : target;
    if (!self.d) {
      self.error = '[CountUp] target is null or undefined'
      return false;
    }
    self.startVal = Number(startVal);
    self.endVal = Number(endVal);
    // error checks
    if (ensureNumber(self.startVal) && ensureNumber(self.endVal)) {
      self.decimals = Math.max(0, decimals || 0);
      self.dec = Math.pow(10, self.decimals);
      self.duration = Number(duration) * 1000 || 2000;
      self.countDown = (self.startVal > self.endVal);
      self.frameVal = self.startVal;
      self.initialized = true;
      return true;
    } else {
      self.error = '[CountUp] startVal (' + startVal + ') or endVal (' + endVal + ') is not a number';
      return false;
    }
  };

  // Print value to target
  self.printValue = function(value) {
    var result = self.options.formattingFn(value);

    console.log(value);

    if (self.d.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      this.d.value = result;
    } else if (self.d.tagName === 'text' || self.d.tagName === 'tspan') {
      this.d.textContent = result;
    } else {
      this.d.innerHTML = result;
    }
  };

  self.count = function(timestamp) {

    if (!self.startTime) {
      self.startTime = timestamp;
    }

    self.timestamp = timestamp;
    var progress = timestamp - self.startTime;
    self.remaining = self.duration - progress;

    // to ease or not to ease
    if (self.options.useEasing) {
      if (self.countDown) {
        self.frameVal = self.startVal - self.options.easingFn(progress, 0, self.startVal - self.endVal, self.duration);
      } else {
        self.frameVal = self.options.easingFn(progress, self.startVal, self.endVal - self.startVal, self.duration);
      }
    } else {
      if (self.countDown) {
        self.frameVal = self.startVal - ((self.startVal - self.endVal) * (progress / self.duration));
      } else {
        self.frameVal = self.startVal + (self.endVal - self.startVal) * (progress / self.duration);
      }
    }

    // don't go past endVal since progress can exceed duration in the last frame
    if (self.countDown) {
      self.frameVal = (self.frameVal < self.endVal) ? self.endVal : self.frameVal;
    } else {
      self.frameVal = (self.frameVal > self.endVal) ? self.endVal : self.frameVal;
    }

    // decimal
    self.frameVal = Math.round(self.frameVal * self.dec) / self.dec;

    // format and print value
    self.printValue(self.frameVal);

    // whether to continue
    if (progress < self.duration) {
      self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
    } else {
      if (self.callback) self.callback();
    }
  };
  // start your animation
  self.start = function(callback) {
    if (!self.initialize()) return;
    self.callback = callback;
    self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
  };
  // toggles pause/resume animation
  self.pauseResume = function() {
    if (!self.paused) {
      self.paused = true;
      cancelAnimationFrame(self.rAF);
    } else {
      self.paused = false;
      delete self.startTime;
      self.duration = self.remaining;
      self.startVal = self.frameVal;
      requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
    }
  };
  // reset to startVal so animation can be run again
  self.reset = function() {
    self.paused = false;
    delete self.startTime;
    self.initialized = false;
    if (self.initialize()) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(self.rAF);
      self.printValue(self.startVal);
    }
  };
  // pass a new endVal and start animation
  self.update = function(newEndVal) {
    if (!self.initialize()) return;
    newEndVal = Number(newEndVal);
    if (!ensureNumber(newEndVal)) {
      self.error = '[CountUp] update() - new endVal is not a number: ' + newEndVal;
      return;
    }
    self.error = '';
    if (newEndVal === self.frameVal) return;
    cancelAnimationFrame(self.rAF);
    self.paused = false;
    delete self.startTime;
    self.startVal = self.frameVal;
    self.endVal = newEndVal;
    self.countDown = (self.startVal > self.endVal);
    self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
  };

  // format startVal on initialization
  if (self.initialize()) self.printValue(self.startVal);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply... Sorry I'm learning javascript and I want pure javascript code without HTML, I'll fire the code using a button in Storyline

Comment: When I try to invoke go function using go(); this error occurs: (index):33 Uncaught TypeError: CountUp is not a constructor
    at go ((index):33)
    at window.onload ((index):30)

Comment: Try it again. Probably because the way `CountUp` was written, it wasn't defined when `go` was run. Changing it a bit will trigger function hoisting and the error should go away.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now :) although I can't understand what's the difference between "var CountUp = function" and "function CountUp"?!

Comment: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html